# OpenLayers make feature not clickable

Tags: openlayers-2, features

I have defined an `OpenLayers.Select.Control` - I need only `hoveron` and `hoverout` events. I have implemented it using callbacks that and it works. But I need to disable just on feature clicking functionality. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set

```
hover: true
```

Copypaste from documentation: Select on mouse over and deselect on mouse out.  If true, this ignores clicks and only listens to mouse moves (http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Control/SelectFeature-js.html#OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature.hover).

Listen for featurehighlighted and featureunhighlighted events.